# Detect items in a chest using command blocks

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to detect a chest with coal blocks and I entered in:

```
/testforblock -673 57 -195 chest 2 {Items:[{id:173s,Damage:0s,Slot:1b,Count:1b}]}
```

But below that it says:

> -673,57,-195 did not have the required NBT keys

I'm running Minecraft 1.8.

Answer (score 1):

Item IDs are saved in 1.8+ as strings containing the name IDs. You should **not** be using numerical IDs anymore.

```
/testforblock -673 57 -195 chest 2 {Items:[{id:"minecraft:coal_block",Damage:0s,Slot:1b,Count:1b}]}
```

Comment: it still says that -673,57,-195 did not have the required NBT keys

Comment: @phoenix And there is a coal block in slot 1 (keep in mind that slot numbers are offset by 1; 0 means the very first visual slot) with a stack-size of exactly 1? The command works fine for me when those requirements are met.